# Comparing Meta-Analysis of identical studies

Tags: meta-analysis

I'm doing an extracurricular programme at my university as part of which we have to write a review article. My supervisor agreed to a meta-analysis. I want to investigate whether the preprocessing of the data (log-transformation of RTs & Outlier trimming/ only outlier trimming/ only log-transformation / raw data) influences the outcome across multiple studies.

For that, I want to analyse all studies on that topic, that my supervisor´s lab ran (ca 10 unpublished + two published papers from other labs) with each of the possible preprocessing pathways. I then planned to conduct a meta-analysis of each pathway separately and compare the mean effect sizes of each preprocessing pathway. How do I account for the fact that each of the 4 meta analyses uses the same studies? Because I think I remember that meta-analysis assumes independence.

Some advice and/or literature would be appreciated. Particularly, if anyone knows a (free) programme that allows me to correct for dependency, that´d be great.
And how do I best compare the mean effect sizes of the different meta-analyses? I found a post on here suggesting simply subtracting ES 1 from ES 2. Or should I run a meta-analysis again?

I'm willing to use any free non-programming based program, *i.e,* preferably not R.

Comment: It is not clear why you want to do meta-analysis if your goal is to compare the effect of the transformations as it seems indirect and throwing away much information.

Comment: A previous paper showed an effect of pre-processing on significance in a sample study. And I thought effect sizes contain more information than p-values.

Do you happen to know a more direct approach to synthesize the influence of the pre-processing pathways across studies?

Comment: Would it not be more direct to compare the four methods per each study on some metric and then look at them?

Answer (score 0):

Calculating effect sizes does not require running a meta-analysis- meta-analysis is just a way to aggregate effect sizes. If you did need to run a meta-analysis for some reason, though, you would probably need to use something like metafor or metasem in R to account for nonindependence. You would test all effects in a single model and then compare using pathway as a moderator variable and dataset as a grouping variable. Comprehensive Meta Analysis (which is non-programming-based) doesn't handle nested effect sizes, to my knowledge.